# How to swap the first vowel and last vowel of a String using Java?

Tags: java

I am making a method called "Swap" where it takes in a string in the parameters. My goal is to swap the first and last vowel of the String. That's it.

My way of finding this goes like this:

(fVowel is the index of the first vowel)

(lVowel is the index of the last vowel)

(newWord is a string declared above)

(firstVowel is a character from the first vowel)

(lastVowel is a character from the last vowel)

All of these have been done ^, just need the algorithm below to be accurate.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
   
        newWord += s.charAt(i);
        if(i == fVowel)
        {
            newWord += lastVowel;
        }
        if(i == lVowel)
        {
            newWord = s.substring(i-1, i);
            newWord += firstVowel;
            /*
            newWord.substring(i, i+1);
            newWord += firstVowel;
            */
        }

    }
    System.out.println(newWord);
    return newWord;
}
```

I am having trouble right now removing the character from the original string. I tried using substrings, but I can't seem to have it figured out. Any help would be appreciated. Here's an example of how it is suppose to work:

Main

```
swap("Red is rad");
swap("Hello Cats");
```

Output:

```
Rad is red
Hallo Cets
```

Comment: Instead of that if statement, Add all the vowels to an arraylist. Then you can use `ArrayList.contans(string);`

Comment: There is also a performance bug in your implementation: You should move both inner loops outside. This makes your runtime linear (instead of quadratic). And you can even optimize these loops.

Comment: @CoronA Thank you. I will edit the code above. Your answer below was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm would work if you replace the part starting with `newWord += s.charAt(i);` with:

```
if(i == fVowel) {
  newWord += lastVowel;
} else if(i == lVowel) {
  newWord += firstVowel;
} else {
  newWord += s.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). It's a one-liner:

```java
String swap(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("^([^aeiou]*)([aeiou])(.*)([aeiou])([^aeiou]*)$", "$1$4$3$2$5");
}
```

To explain: the regex is bounded by `^...$`, meaning it must match the entire string. The string is then matched as 5 groups, using `(...)` to capture each group:

1. `[^aeiou]*` matches 0 or more non-vowels,
2. `[aeiou]` matches a single vowel,
3. `.*` matches anything, 0 or more characters,
4. Same as 2,
5. Same as 1.

The replacement is then `$1$4$3$2$5` meaning we replace the whole string with the non-vowels at the start, then the vowel captured by group 4, then the "anything" between the two vowels, then the vowel captured by group 2, then the non-vowels at the end. The original string would be `$1$2$3$4$5`, so compared to that, the replacement has `$2` and `$4` swapped.

If the string does not have at least two vowels, then the original string will be returned because there is no match to replace.

Comment: That is a very high level of expertise of solving this. I appreciate it, however, this is way beyond from what I learned in class. I appreciate it a lot though.

Comment: Short, but hardly readable and terribly performant.

Comment: @CoronA Exactly. Everything that was written in the post should have been written in code comments. :) And then the code isn't very short anymore.

Comment: How about `s.replaceAll("([aeiou])(.*)([aeiou])", "$3$2$1")`?

Comment: @CoronA What do you mean with "terribly performant"? I'm not used to Java, but isn't it much faster than the solution you're indulging in with your answer?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy Java regular expressions (and the default implementations of most other languages) do backtracking on the Kleene Star. This leads to a quadratic runtime. Many developers are not aware of this. The problem itself is solvable in linear runtime (first find the first an last vowel in linear time, than rebuild the string in linear time). Besides - Your proposal is possibly faster because backtracking stops after one character. My patch is not a complete solution - but I can imagine an algorithm with linear runtime containing the proposed snippet.

Comment: @CoronA Hmm, I know regexes in general can take quadratic time or even worse, but I don't see it in this case. What strings would lead to quadratic runtime with kaya3's solution?

Comment: @CoronA Backtracking can lead to much worse than quadratic runtime, but it depends on the regex. Most sensible regexes should be linear time. The main performance issue here is likely to be the time it takes to compile the regex, and whether the implementation will cache the compiled pattern, or compile it again each time. Some Python implementations do this, but Java implementations probably don't, so if performance is critical then doing `Pattern.compile` once and then using the `Pattern` object is preferable. Likewise, if performance is critical for your answer, a `char` array or ...

Comment: ... `StringBuilder` should be used instead of `+=` in a loop, and the searches for the first and last vowels should be done with standard linear searches instead of nested loops (as in the OP's code). Given that both of our answers are clearly not optimised, I don't think it makes sense to worry about their exact performance, but if you have some reason to think this particular regex will be worse than linear time (other than "some regexes can be worse than linear time") then please elaborate.

Comment: The String with just one vowel processes the last character almost n times. before rejecting the whole pattern. And I think @kaya3 is right: If performance was important, the accepted solution should have looked another way.

Comment: @CoronA *"The String with just one vowel processes the last character almost n times"* - I don't think that's true, and I don't see that happening when I try it in the regex101.com debugger. What part of the regex would do that?

Comment: The pattern is in fact not really quadratic runtime - so I am wrong on this judgement. And @Kaya3 is right: The main performance problems occur from not buffering and not precompiling the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String x = "Hello cats";
    int i = 1;int j = 7;

    String newWord = x.substring(0, i) + x.charAt(j) + x.substring(i+1, j) + x.charAt(i) + 
            x.substring(j+1, x.length());
           System.out.println(newWord);
```

This will give you your desired output.